# Get all public holidays date between two dates and hold in array in PHP Procedural

Tags: php

Anyone can help me to get all public holidays date between 2 dates?

I have a code to count the number of working days then I'm here asking for help on how to
get all public holidays between 2 date (the $given_date and $target_date) and hold it in array for me to replace the hard coded value of $holiday variable.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");

function getWorkingDays($startDate, $endDate, $offdays, $holidays)
{
    $endDate = strtotime($endDate);
    $startDate = strtotime($startDate);
    $days = ($endDate - $startDate) / 86400 + 1;
    $counter = 0;
    for($i = 1; $i <= $days; $i++)
    {
        $the_first_day_of_week = date("N", $startDate);
        $startDate += 86400;
        if(!in_array($the_first_day_of_week, $offdays) && !in_array(date("Y-m-d",$startDate), $holidays))
        {
            $counter++;
        }
    }   

    return $counter;
}

$given_date = "2021-10-20";
$target_date = "2021-11-06";
$holidays = array("2021-11-01", "2021-11-02");
$offdays = array(5,6);
echo getWorkingDays($given_date, $target_date, $offdays, $holidays);

?>
```

Comment: Public holidays in which country? Do you have a list of these? What format are they in?

Comment: It is common that public holidays of a country may change each year (e.g. Easter does not have a fixed date), so the normal way is to put the holidays in a db table and you put the dates at the start of each year . Then the system will check against this list to calculate the working days

Comment: @AndyGee Manila, Philippines. I used this default time zone date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");

Comment: @KenLee This is noted and I will try your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Here's last year's data: https://holidayapi.com/v1/holidays?pretty&country=PH&year=2020&key=fb9afc33-a6f2-412f-974d-29be230f6288

Comment: This year's data: https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=2021&country=67